# YouTube video doesn't play continuously on iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, youtube

I am programming on iPhone web using YouTube JavaScript API.
I have a list of video like that:

```
var playlist = "9Adbr-lipP8,OCK5FX0Y-7A,0k2Zzkw_-0I";

function onPlayerReady(event) 
{
if (player) 
    {
        try 
        {
            player.loadPlaylist(playlist);

        }
        catch (err) {}
    }
}
```

The player plays first video as well, but the second cannot be played. I see that the second has fullsize Ads at the beginning (if you open it on YouTube site). That causes the error:

> Your browser does not currently recognize any of the video formats available.
> Click here to visit our frequently asked questions about HTML5 video.

My source runs well in Android, only iPhone has the problem. And it works well if playlist has only one that video. Maybe QuickTime doesn't support Ads (I don't know).

I am very appreciate if any help.